# Salvar array em uma variável em php

Tags: php, array

Como salvar todos os dados de um array em uma variável só ? exemplo eu chamo uma query de uma determianda coluna do banco e gero um while e queria por em uma variável.

Talvez o certo seria Junta elementos de uma matriz em uma string?

```
$sql_lista3 = mysql_query("select * from empresa as c1
                           inner join empresa_has_viagem as c2 on c1.em_id= c2.empresa_em_id
                           where viagem_via_id=37 order by viagem_via_id;"); 

while($resultado3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_lista3)){
        $campanha = array($resultado3['em_nomefantasia']);
};

$resultado = implode(",", $campanha); //essa seria a variavel
```

Comment: Qual é o objetivo desse código? `$nada` deve receber o que? nome parece bem intuitivo :D

Comment: na verdade seria o resultado @rray

Comment: vc quer uma string delimitada por vírgulas isso?

Comment: Deve receber dodos os dados de uma determinada tabela do select feito.

Comment: isso mesmo @rray

Comment: Faça assim `$campanha[] = $resultado3['em_nomefantasia'];` veja se é o que você quer.

Comment: isso mesmo correto amigo obrigado vacilo meu em não por $campanha[] talvez tenha sido falta de atenção rs a dias sem dormir direito kkk valew mano.

Comment: Para ver a estrutura de um array use `print_r($var)`, sempre tira as dúvidas de como usar ele.

Comment: Olha que tinha feito isso e apareceu somente uma empresa rs então vi que tinha erro pois era mais de uma.

Answer (score 4):

Mude esse seu trecho de codigo:

```
while($resultado3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_lista3)){
    $campanha = array($resultado3['em_nomefantasia']);

};
```

Para esse:

```
while($resultado3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_lista3)){
    $campanha[] = $resultado3['em_nomefantasia'];

};
```